# Pythonic way of copying deep sublists

Tags: python

I have a deep list `a=[[1, 2], 3]` for which I want to copy the first entry of the first list multiple times to get `[[1, 1, 1, 2], 3]`.

My try:

```
number_of_multiplications = 2
for _ in range(number_of_multiplications):
  a[0] = a[0][:1] + a[0]
```

Question: Is there a way to do this without the loop?

Bonus: How can I make sure that I create a deep copy and not a shallow copy of the element I'm copying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = [[1, 2], 3]
number_of_multiplications = 2
a[0] = [a[0][0]] * (number_of_multiplications + 1) + a[0][1:]
print(a)    # [[1, 1, 1, 2], 3]
```

What we have here  is list multiplication in 1st phase `[a[0][0]] * (number_of_multiplications + 1)` (which gives `[1,1,1]`) and list concatenation on 2nd phase `[1,1,1] + a[0][1:]` (where `a[0][1:]` is a slice of remaining entries of the crucial sublist resided in `a[0]`)

Comment: Thanks! In your opinion: What is the crucial part that makes your code a deep copy? I still don't understand that because I had problems with shallow copies.

Comment: @Carsten, actually I would not call it as "copying deep sublists". What we have here  is list multiplication in 1st phase `[a[0][0]] * (number_of_multiplications + 1)` (which gives `[1,1,1]`) and list concatenation on 2nd phase `[1,1,1] + a[0][1:]` (where `a[0][1:]` is a slice of remaining entries of the crucial sublist resided in `a[0]`)

Answer (score 1):

```
number_of_multiplications = 2
a = [[1, 2], 3]
a[0]=a[0][:1]*number_of_multiplications+a[0]
```

Comment: Thanks! In your opinion: What is the crucial part that makes your code a deep copy? I still don't understand that because I had problems with shallow copies.